# "over quota" error, how to find quota name or logs

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

App engine all apps are failing in 2 hours of work after quota reset on Midnight.

App version redirected to 503 "Over Quota

This application is temporarily over its serving quota. Please try again later."

**How to find out what quota is reached ?**

Checked out https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails and https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails/history 
but it doesn't contain any overused quota

Answer (score 1):

It is expected to receive the 503 message if you are over the quota, as indicated in the "[When a resource is depleted](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#When_a_Resource_is_Depleted)" sub-chapter of the "Quotas" documentation page.

You are able to monitor your quota status at any moment in the developers' console dashboard, under "Billing status".